# How to serve images from a private folder from Node.js to a website/application in a restful manner?

Tags: javascript, android, image, node.js

Hey how can I serve images from a private folder from Node.js to a website/application in a restful manner? I currently been saving the images in an img folder that is in the public folder, while saving the id of the image in the db and when a user goes to his profile, his picture is loaded by looking up the picture id and setting the path of the picture to public > img > id, however this is not good for two reasons...

One: The picture is public available for anyone...
Two: This means all pictures are loaded as the pictures are in the website's resources...

There are probably more problems as well... but I am trying to figure out how to serve it if I changed the path of the images to a private folder, how do I allow a website to ask for a user's profile picture and be able to serve it back or if a user going to his profile on an android application?

Also, should the images being server, be static or something, I do plan on using Nginx in the future...

Comment: How would anyone ever see the image if it was private, and how do you show an image without loading it? What you're asking for seems really strange?

Comment: You said it yourself: you want it restful, so you should have routes for user-specific resources. Yes, they can be on disk. static is only a helper-middleware. Most commonly it is used for exposing basic public resources. PS: you can use static from within a route.

Comment: Ok, well private so that it can only be viewed by the user who uploaded and those that he is "friends with, etc"...

Answer (score 4):

### Update - For Express 4.x using [`res.sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

```js
app.get('/user/:uid/photos/:file', function (req, res) {
  var uid = req.params.uid
  var file = req.params.file

  req.user.mayViewFilesFrom(uid, function (yes) {
    if (yes) {
      res.sendFile('/uploads/' + uid + '/' + file)
    } else {
      res.status(403).send("Sorry! You can't see that.")
    }
  })
})
```

Security against malicious up-paths `/../` is [included](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/blob/de073ed3237ade9ff71c61673a34474b30e5d45b/index.js#L538).

### Old

```js
  var fs = require('fs')
    
    function(req, res) {
      var id = req.param('id')
      fs.exists('/private/img/'+id, function(exists) {
        if(exists) res.sendfile('/private/img/'+id)
        else res.end('err')
      })
    }
```

Comment: `res.sendfile` it's not part of the node.js http core library. It comes from frameworks  `mean`, `sails`, `express` etc etc...

Comment: I am using express, also, I see that this is including the private route, but what is actually making it private?

Comment: Simply posting a code is not very helpful. Could you please add more info on how to secure /private directory so that it is not publicly accessible? And how the code works despite the directory being private?